# Find longest word in dictionary that is a subsequence of a given string (Google TechDevGuide)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This a Google interview questions that is now a problem in Google's Foundations of Programming course. I was trying to understand the solution to the following problem:

https://techdevguide.withgoogle.com/paths/foundational/find-longest-word-in-dictionary-that-subsequence-of-given-string#code-challenge

*"Given a string S and a set of words D, find the longest word in D that is a subsequence of S.
Word W is a subsequence of S if some number of characters, possibly zero, can be deleted from S to form W, without reordering the remaining characters.
Note: D can appear in any format (list, hash table, prefix tree, etc.
For example, given the input of S = "abppplee" and D = {"able", "ale", "apple", "bale", "kangaroo"} the correct output would be "apple" "*

So the main doubt I have is in the section the specifies An Optimal method O(N+L)  for small alphabet. In the previous approach i.e O(N + L log N), the author builds a hash table mapping characters -> sorted indexes in String

So for "abppple", the hash table is:

```
a -> [0]
b -> [1]
p -> [2,3,4]
l -> [5]
e -> [6]
```

In the optimal approach for small alphabet, it is mentioned using a dense vector representation instead of the above sparse vector representation.

```
p -> [2, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

What are they trying to represent? The string S = "abppplee" does have 8 characters but I don't get what the dense vector is representing? Is it an error or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, this vector should address the question (with `Y` set to character *p*)

> Given my last matched character was at index X and my next character
>   to match is Y, where does this match occur?

In other words, if you are at index `i` in the original string, the element of the vector `p[i]` tells you where is the closest next character *p* in the string.

To be more specific, the original string is `s=abppplee` and we want to verify:

```
p -> [2, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

This means that if we are at index `0`, the closest *p* is at index `2`. For index `1`, the closest *p* is also at `2`. If we are at index `2`, the closest next *p* is at position `3`, etc. The values `-1` signify that there is no *p* in the rest of the string (for example at position `4`, the remaining characters are indeed just `lee`, thus there is no *p*).